# Windows Default Context Menu on Borderless Windows Form replace not working Options with custom ones

Tags: vb.net, winforms, contextmenu, default, user32

I created an Borderless Windows Form and added the functionalities of the default System Header:

### Moving:

```
Private m_blnMouseDown As Boolean = False
  Private m_utdMouseOffset As Point

  ' Left mouse button pressed
  Private Sub BorderlessMove_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles tlpHeader.MouseDown
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
      ' Get the new position
      Dim mouseRelative As Point = Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position)
      m_utdMouseOffset = New Point(-mouseRelative.X, -mouseRelative.Y)
      ' Set that left button is pressed
      m_blnMouseDown = True
    End If
  End Sub

  ' MouseMove used to check if mouse cursor is moving
  Private Sub BorderlessMove_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles tlpHeader.MouseMove
    If m_blnMouseDown Then
      Dim mousePos As Point = Control.MousePosition
      ' Get the new form position
      mousePos.Offset(m_utdMouseOffset.X, m_utdMouseOffset.Y)
      Me.Location = mousePos
    End If
  End Sub

  ' Left mouse button released, form should stop moving
  Private Sub BorderlessMove_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles tlpHeader.MouseUp
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
      m_blnMouseDown = False
    End If
  End Sub
```

### Resizing:

```
Private Enum ResizeState
    North
    NE
    East
    SE
    South
    SW
    West
    NW
    None
  End Enum

  Private m_utdResizeState As ResizeState = ResizeState.None

  Private Const GRIP_SIZE As Int32 = 5

  Private Sub BorderlessResize_FormLoad(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Const DGRIP_SIZE As Int32 = GRIP_SIZE * 2

    Dim Sizes As New Dictionary(Of String, Size)
    Sizes.Add("Horizontal", New Size(Me.Width - DGRIP_SIZE * 2, GRIP_SIZE))
    Sizes.Add("Vertical", New Size(GRIP_SIZE, Me.Height - DGRIP_SIZE * 2))
    Sizes.Add("HEdge", New Size(DGRIP_SIZE, GRIP_SIZE))
    Sizes.Add("VEdge", New Size(GRIP_SIZE, DGRIP_SIZE))

    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeNorth", ResizeState.North, Sizes.Item("Horizontal"), New Point(DGRIP_SIZE, 0), (AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Right) Or AnchorStyles.Left)
    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeNE_H", ResizeState.NE, Sizes.Item("HEdge"), New Point(Me.Width - DGRIP_SIZE, 0), AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Right)
    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeNE_V", ResizeState.NE, Sizes.Item("VEdge"), New Point(Me.Width - GRIP_SIZE, 0), AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Right)
    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeEast", ResizeState.East, Sizes.Item("Vertical"), New Point(Me.Width - GRIP_SIZE, DGRIP_SIZE), (AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Right) Or AnchorStyles.Bottom)
    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeSE_H", ResizeState.SE, Sizes.Item("HEdge"), New Point(Me.Width - DGRIP_SIZE, Me.Height - GRIP_SIZE), AnchorStyles.Right Or AnchorStyles.Bottom)
    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeSE_V", ResizeState.SE, Sizes.Item("VEdge"), New Point(Me.Width - GRIP_SIZE, Me.Height - DGRIP_SIZE), AnchorStyles.Right Or AnchorStyles.Bottom)
    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeSouth", ResizeState.South, Sizes.Item("Horizontal"), New Point(DGRIP_SIZE, Me.Height - GRIP_SIZE), (AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Right) Or AnchorStyles.Left)
    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeSW_H", ResizeState.SW, Sizes.Item("HEdge"), New Point(0, Me.Height - GRIP_SIZE), AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left)
    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeSW_V", ResizeState.SW, Sizes.Item("VEdge"), New Point(0, Me.Height - DGRIP_SIZE), AnchorStyles.Bottom Or AnchorStyles.Left)
    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeWest", ResizeState.West, Sizes.Item("Vertical"), New Point(0, DGRIP_SIZE), (AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Left) Or AnchorStyles.Bottom)
    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeNW_H", ResizeState.NW, Sizes.Item("HEdge"), New Point(0, 0), AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Left)
    GenerateTransparentPanel("pnlResizeNW_V", ResizeState.NW, Sizes.Item("VEdge"), New Point(0, 0), AnchorStyles.Top Or AnchorStyles.Left)

  End Sub

  Private Sub GenerateTransparentPanel(name As String, tag As ResizeState, size As Size, location As Point, anchors As AnchorStyles)
    Dim panel As TransparentPanel = New TransparentPanel()
    panel.Anchor = anchors
    panel.Location = location
    panel.Name = name
    panel.Size = size
    panel.Tag = tag
    AddHandler panel.MouseDown, AddressOf BorderlessResize_MouseDown
    AddHandler panel.MouseMove, AddressOf BorderlessResize_MouseMove
    AddHandler panel.MouseUp, AddressOf BorderlessResize_MouseUp
    AddHandler panel.MouseEnter, AddressOf BorderlessResize_MouseEnter
    AddHandler panel.MouseLeave, AddressOf BorderlessResize_MouseLeave
    Me.Controls.Add(panel)
    panel.BringToFront()
  End Sub

  Private Sub BorderlessResize_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    Debug.Write("MouseDown")
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
      m_utdResizeState = DirectCast(sender, Control).Tag
    End If
  End Sub

  Protected Sub BorderlessResize_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    If m_utdResizeState <> ResizeState.None Then
      BorderlessResize_ResizeForm(m_utdResizeState)
      Refresh()
    End If
  End Sub
  Protected Sub BorderlessResize_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    BorderlessResize_UpdateCursor(DirectCast(sender, Control).Tag)
  End Sub
  Protected Sub BorderlessResize_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
  End Sub

  Private Sub BorderlessResize_UpdateCursor(state As ResizeState)
    If (state = ResizeState.East OrElse state = ResizeState.West) Then
      Me.Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE
    ElseIf (state = ResizeState.North OrElse state = ResizeState.South) Then
      Me.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS
    ElseIf (state = ResizeState.SE OrElse state = ResizeState.NW) Then
      Me.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE
    ElseIf (state = ResizeState.NE OrElse state = ResizeState.SW) Then
      Me.Cursor = Cursors.SizeNESW
    Else Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Sub BorderlessResize_ResizeForm(ResizeVal As ResizeState)
    Dim Location As Point = New Point(Cursor.Position.X - Me.Left, Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Top)
    Select Case ResizeVal
      Case ResizeState.North
        If Me.Height - Location.Y <= Me.MinimumSize.Height Then Return
        Me.Height = Me.Height - Location.Y
        Me.Top = Me.Top + Location.Y
        Exit Select
      Case ResizeState.South
        Me.Height = Location.Y
        Exit Select
      Case ResizeState.East
        Me.Width = Location.X
        Exit Select
      Case ResizeState.West
        If Me.Width - Location.X <= Me.MinimumSize.Width Then Return
        Me.Width = Me.Width - Location.X
        Me.Left = Me.Left + Location.X
        Exit Select
      Case ResizeState.NE
        BorderlessResize_ResizeForm(ResizeState.North)
        BorderlessResize_ResizeForm(ResizeState.East)
        Exit Select
      Case ResizeState.SE
        BorderlessResize_ResizeForm(ResizeState.South)
        BorderlessResize_ResizeForm(ResizeState.East)
        Exit Select
      Case ResizeState.SW
        BorderlessResize_ResizeForm(ResizeState.South)
        BorderlessResize_ResizeForm(ResizeState.West)
        Exit Select
      Case ResizeState.NW
        BorderlessResize_ResizeForm(ResizeState.North)
        BorderlessResize_ResizeForm(ResizeState.West)
        Exit Select
    End Select
  End Sub

  Protected Sub BorderlessResize_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
      m_utdResizeState = ResizeState.None
    End If
  End Sub
```

### Default Context Menu

```
  Private Const WS_SYSMENU As Integer = &H80000
  Private Const WS_MINIMIZEBOX As Integer = &H20000
  Private Const WS_MAXIMIZEBOX As Integer = &H10000
  Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
    Get
      Dim p = MyBase.CreateParams
      p.Style = WS_SYSMENU + WS_MINIMIZEBOX + WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
      Return p
    End Get
  End Property

  <DllImport("user32.dll")>
  Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer,
      ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
  End Function
  Private Const WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU = &H313
  Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseDown(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnMouseDown(e)
    Dim p = MousePosition.X + (MousePosition.Y * &H10000)
    SendMessage(Me.Handle, WM_POPUPSYSTEMMENU, 0, p)
  End Sub
```

Moving and Resizing works just fine, but my Context Menu is always displayed in the top left corner and `MOVE` and `SIZE` Options are not working because they need the Default Window Frame which I removed.

So is there a possibility to implement my solutions for Moving and Resizing into the Context Menu?

Is

Comment: Bottom snippet works just fine to position the system menu and to get the Move menu command to work.  I'd have to guess that not being selective enough about the particular mouse click that should be handled causes trouble with the other mouse event handlers.  Do *not* call MyBase.OnMouseDown(e) when you are going to use the event to display the menu.  And do consider rewriting the moving/resizing code, it should be done by altering the return value for the WM_NCHITTEST message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION 1

with WndPrc Overwrite

```
Private Sub Header_MouseDown(sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then
      Dim p As IntPtr = ((MousePosition.Y * WindowStyles.WS_MAXIMIZEBOX) + (MousePosition.X And &HFFFF))
      Dim test As IntPtr = SendMessage(Me.Handle, WindowMessages.WM_POPUPSYSMENU, 0, p)
    End If
  End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    If (m.Msg = WindowMessages.WM_SYSCOMMAND)
        'Do SOmething with m.wParam
    Else
      MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End If
  End Sub
```

---

### SOLUTION 2

with TrackMenuBar

```
Private Sub Header_MouseDown(sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs)
    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Right Then'Alternate Solution

    Dim sysMenu As IntPtr = GetSystemMenu(Me.Handle, False)
    Dim cmd As IntPtr = TrackPopupMenu(
               sysMenu,
               TrackPopupMenuOptions.TOPALIGN Or
               TrackPopupMenuOptions.NOANIMATION Or
               TrackPopupMenuOptions.RETURNCMD Or
               TrackPopupMenuOptions.LEFTALIGN Or
               TrackPopupMenuOptions.RIGHTBUTTON,
               MousePosition.X,
               MousePosition.Y,
               IntPtr.Zero,
               Me.Handle,
               IntPtr.Zero)
    'Do Something with cmd
    End If
End Sub
```